# How to unlock the bootloader of a Meizu MX4 with Flyme 5.1.11G

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, meizu-mx4

I have bought myself a Meizu Mx4 with the intention to use Ubuntu Touch (I know about the discussions nowadays with quitting etc. but I am interested in a technical solution to this). I used the official tutorial here: [Install Ubuntu Touch](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

But I got stuck when I tried to unlock the phone:

```
sudo fastboot oem 
FAILED (remote: unknown OEM command)
```

After some reading I got to know that this problem is known to MX4s with Flyme OS because Flyme is using a sepcial filesystem which is incompatible with Ubuntu Touch. See:
[Flashing a MX4 with Ubuntu Touch is not a good idea](http://news.softpedia.com/news/buying-a-meizu-mx4-with-android-to-flash-ubuntu-is-not-a-good-idea-485495.shtml)

I still want to use Ubuntu Touch on this phone, which is officially known as a "Ubuntu Phone"...

Any hints and suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: No recommended but it may be possible if - and only if - your Meizu is the "international" version. The version for mainland China has a closed bootloader and there's nothing you can do about it and has nothing to do with the other problem you're already aware of.  Anything to do with Android (or the Android based Flyme) is off-topic here. You may try at https://android.stackexchange.com/ but expect the exact same answer. In a nutshell, it's a waste of time and you may brick the phone *and* void the warranty.

Comment: okay thanks for your advice...as far as I see I do have the international version: 
Build-Nummer: Flyme 5.1.11.0G

…I know that it is a little bitt off-topic but it said on the install page of ubuntu touch, that problems should be posted here...

Comment: **Warning: this can break your phone.** Here (https://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-mx/general/tutorial-easy-unlock-bootloader-flash-t3239052) you can find how to unlock the bootloader of the Meizu MX4. Please note that  **you need first to downgrade the ROM to the 4.2.8.2A version (exactly)**. Would be great if you can document the procedure if you can unlock the bootloader.